# Syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR?

Tags: php, parsing, syntax

PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR in ...

```
tpl->set( '[complaint]', "<a href=\"javascript:AddComplaint('" . $row['id'] . "', 'comments')\">" );
```

What in this code causing problem, please help to find answer.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the dollar sign before your variable name:

```
tpl->set( '[complaint]', "<a href=\"javascript:AddComplaint('" . $row['id'] . "', 'comments')\">" );
```

should be:

```
$tpl->set( '[complaint]', "<a href=\"javascript:AddComplaint('" . $row['id'] . "', 'comments')\">" );
```